# Image of a parametrised curve and its geometrical meaning

Tags: complex-analysis, plane-curves, complex-integration

$\gamma_1(t)= t^2 + i\, t^4 , t\in [ -1, 1]$

which is the Image of this curve and / or what is the geometrical description of the set of points

$ z : z=\gamma_1(t)$

I am helping a friend study Complex Analysis and we've come across this exercise, in the Complex / Contour Integration Chapter and we would welcome any help as we are not sure what to do.

The same is required for $\gamma_2(t)= t^3 + i\, |t^3| , t\in [ -1, 1]$  but my guess is  that the methodology will be the same as above.

Please excuse my english. In my language the term used is translated in orbit or trajectory  of the curve. Reading the definition given in the plane-curves section, I think that the term is curve, but I'm referring to the image of these $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ functions.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that you can identify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$: the point $x+iy$ corresponds to the point $(x,y)$. So the problem is to draw the image of the function $t \mapsto (t^2,t^4)$ in the plane.

You might first try finding the image of the curve for $t \in [0,1]$. Remember that the image of the curve does not change if you reparameterize the curve, so $\gamma_1([0,1])$ is the same as the image of the map defined by $s \mapsto (s,s^2)$ for $s \in [0,1]$. To get the image for $t \in [-1,0]$, think about how to use the symmetries of the defining functions.

Comment: $\gamma_1$ is an even function so the image for t∈[−1,0] should be symmetric as to the image of $\gamma_1$([0,1]),correct?

Comment: @helplessKirk : do you get any new points in the image from changing $t$ to $-t$? Remember that this is not the same thing as graphing a function, because the $x$-axis does not correspond to the domain.

Comment: Also note that this part of the argument will be slightly different for $t \mapsto (t^3, |t^3|)$.

Comment: I understand that the part will be different for t↦(t3,|t3|).

Comment: I was wondering if I can try something like converting $t^2 + \imath t^4$ into an exponential.

Comment: @helplessKirk since $a+ib = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i \theta}$, where $\tan \theta = \frac{b}{a}$, you can write $t^4+it^4 = |t|\sqrt{1+t^2}\operatorname{exp}(i\operatorname{arctan}(t^2))$. What this what you had in mind? (I'm not sure that this helps to describe the image, though.)